# Bitrix. Собственный модуль

Tags: битрикс

Уставил битрикс на apache2 в ubuntu.
 Скачал несколько самодельных модулей из статей и создал из официального сайта пример.
 Ни один модуль не показался в списке модулей и в "Установленные решения".

---

Примеры статей:

http://know-online.com/post/bitrix-module
zapiski.pro/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81

habrahabr.ru/post/196376/

---

На хабре 2 варианта. первый "пустышка", второй "готовый" и оба не видно.
 
Установлено: 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 17.0.9.
Подскажите, если кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим.

Comment: пиши на питоне, не пользуйся php!

Comment: Кирилл, вы еще Facebook предложите все на Python переписать или хотя бы тот же 1С-битрикс...  Хороший программист язык выбирает по задачам, а не по каким-то личным фанатичным предпочтения.

Comment: Так это тестовое задание, тут язык не выберешь)

Comment: Увы,ответ удалили. Информации мало  вопросе. По этому проверяйте для начала: 
1. Ваш модуль  расположен в каталоге /bitrix/modules или /local/modules/  (должен быть в них)
2. Проверяйте название модуля, имя класса в install/index.php  

Прямо с хабра вставляете ни чего не меняя?

Comment: Если берете пример,что в статье ссылка на github он должен быть размещен так  bitrix/modules/maycat.d7dull/ или local/modules/maycat.d7dull/   и дальше уже пошли include.php, install и т.д.

Модуль появляется  в списке Маркетплейс - Устновленные решения

Более подробно можете почитать https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=101&CHAPTER_ID=04793

Comment: копирую как есть, как первый архив, так и второй, только я на самом деле не понял куда прописывать код из первого шага

Comment: Если вы копируете готовый код (по крайней мере с github) не надо вообще ни чего ни куда прописывать.  Все уже вписано. Вот код из первого шага https://github.com/may-cat/bitrix-russianpostjoke/blob/master/russianpostjoke/classes/general/cMainRPJ.php